# How is it that Yaakov Avinu was permitted to marry Zilpah, because she was the sister of Bilhah and Leah already had 4 sons?

Tags: halacha-theory, marriage, imahot-matriarch-mothers

How is it that Yaakov Avinu was permitted to marry Zilpah, because she was the sister of Bilhah and Leah already had 4 sons?

According to Bereishit Rabbah 74:13 Bilhah and Zilpah were also daughters of Lavan.

> וַיַּעַן לָבָן וַיֹּאמֶר לְיַעֲקֹב הַבָּנוֹת בְּנֹתַי וְהַבָּנִים בָּנַי (בראשית לא, מג), אָמַר רַבִּי אָבִין כּוּלְּהוֹן בְּנוֹתָיו הָיוּ, הַבָּנוֹת בְּנֹתַי, הֲרֵי שְׁתַּיִם. (בראשית לא, מג): וְלִבְנֹתַי מָה אֶעֱשֶׂה, הֲרֵי אַרְבַּע. רַבָּנָן מַיְתֵי לָהּ מֵהָכָא (בראשית לא, נ): אִם תְּעַנֶּה אֶת בְּנֹתַי, הֲרֵי שְׁתַּיִם, (בראשית לא, נ): וְאִם תִּקַּח נָשִׁים עַל בְּנֹתַי, הֲרֵי אַרְבַּע.‏
>
> "And Lavan spoke up and said to Ya'akov, 'The girls are my daughters, and the boys my sons.'" (Bereishit 31:43)
>
> Said R. Avin, 'They were all his daughters: "The girls are my daughters" gives two, "And as for my daughters, what should I do?" (Bereishit 31:43) gives [another two equaling] four.'
>
> The Rabbis brought it from here: "If you afflict my daughters" (Bereishit 31:50) gives two. "And if you take other wives in addition to my daughters" gives [another two equaling] four.

We can't say Bilha and Zilpah were from different mothers, as the midrash says they were actually twin sisters, just like Rochel and Leah.

We had been explained by Chazal already, that since Rochel was barren for many years, she relied on the actions of Sara, who took her handmaiden for the same reason, being barren, but Leah did not have that excuse as she had already given birth to 4 sons.  We are also explained by Chazal why Yaakov was permitted to marry Rochel, the 2nd sister, because he had to keep his engagement vow to her, but once again, this does not apply in the case of Zilpah. As a matter of fact, after Zilpah becomes pregnant, Leah calls Yaakov "a Rebel" (בָּגַד) for betraying her!!

> דָּבָר אַחֵר לָמָּה נִקְרֵאת תֵּבָה אַחַת בָּגָד, כְּמוֹ בָּגַדְתָּ בִּי, כְּשֶׁבָּאתָ אֶל שִׁפְחָתִי, כְּאִישׁ שֶׁבָּגַד בְּאֵשֶׁת נְעוּרִים:
>
> Why is it read as one word? בָּגָד is like בָּגַדְתּ ָבִּי, you betrayed me when you came to my handmaid, as a man who has betrayed (בָּגַד) the wife of his youth.

Someone please explain to me why this is not a sin for Yaakov Avinu !?

Comment: There are many explanations as to why Yaakov could marry two sisters - are you asking that the specific explanations you give (unsourced) do not fit with the statement of Chazal that Bilha/Zilpa were also Lavan's daughters?

Comment: Sorry trying to understand the question - why is this any different to Yaakov marrying Rochel and Leah? The answer is that case is because it was before the Torah was given...

Comment: "_We are also explained by Chazal why Yaakov was permitted to marry Rochel, the 2nd sister, because he had to keep his engagement vow to her_ ..." (1) Where do Chazal say that? (2) Where does it say one's engagement vow to the second sister overrides the prohibition against being married to two sisters? (3) (Conversely:) Why did he get to keep Leah? Shouldn't he have divorced her, before marrying Rochel?

Comment: @AKA- The question, since Rashi says Yaakov kept the Taryag(613) mistvahs, by what argument is he allowed to marry Zilpah specifically.  Bilha was not the problem because she was the first of the sisters of bilha and ziplah. the prohibition would have been with zilpah.

Comment: @Joel K- Thanks, you're right, I edited it.

Comment: @Tamir Evan - the question has nothing to do with Rochel and Leah, just zilpah, the twin sister of Jacob's wife Bilha.

Comment: @Dov - the question is pretty clear, we cant use Bilha's halachic "heter" on Zilpah, as both of the redeeming qualities are missing for  to use that answer.

Comment: Is there anything wrong, with let's say the ramban they says he kept the mitzvos only in eretz yisroel? Or the many that say they converted, and were considered converts who have no halachic relations? Or those that explain that he kept them not as commands, but rather to fulfill the metaphysical affect of the mitzvos, and here he could metaphysically accomplish more by marrying sister’s? There are many more approaches as well.

Comment: Another key point to consider is that Bilah was only a half sister to Rochel and Leah from the father, and as I understand it, incest is only if they share the mother, so a kal vachomer would be that bilha would not be considered a prohibited "sister" of Rochel and Leah since they are from different mothers, but only Zilpah would be because she shared the same mother as Bilha.

Comment: @אילפא by that logic, in which it is said that Rochel "conveniently" died around the time they entered the land of Israel, (so Yaacov would not violate the 2 sister law in the holy land), we do not see that Bilha died.

Comment: I believe that the ramban only throws that point in at the end of achrie mos, not in toldos. I would assume that once he was married he was then stuck, as the maharsha says sanhedrin 19b.

Comment: I don't think anybody yet has been able to answer this question.

Comment: @User123    In that case, why would chazal even bother to mention the problem of Yaakov marrying 2 sisters (rochel and leah) if they are all 4 "converts"  then, so why would zilpah and bilha be different from rochel and leah if that regard of being converts?  I was under the impression that that only applied to after matan Torah, when they actually converted.

Comment: The real question is that if Chazal make such deep arguments on why Yaakov could  have technically married Rochel,, where is the concern and the explanations on why he could have married Zilpah?

Comment: Also, Bilhah and Zilpah were not full fledged wives - only concubines - and the prohibition is not to have relations with the sister of your full fledged wife

Comment: The reason I've heard for why yakov could marry rivkah and Leah is that while he voluntarily kept mitzvos he was obligated in sheva mitzvos and since he made a vow (somehow covered under sheva mitzvos) he then had to marry rochel because of a greater obligation to his vows than his voluntary keeping of mitzvos. For bilha and zilpah I'm not sure, however, they were not full wives and perhaps this has something to do with why he could be with them both?

Comment: @User123 Do you know a source for that statement, that a Jew can have relations with 2 concubine sisters? I never heard that.

Comment: @User123 Do you know a source for that statement - that a Jew can have relations with 2 concubine sisters?  Besides that, I believe you are mistaken about the concubine status of Bilha and Zilpah,. Yaakov married them both and they were full wives. וַתִּתֶּן־ל֛וֹ אֶת־בִּלְהָ֥ה שִׁפְחָתָ֖הּ לְאִשָּׁ֑ה וַיָּבֹ֥א אֵלֶ֖יהָ יַֽעֲקֹֽב: "Rachel set Bilhah free and Jacob married her." Ohr Hachayim Genesis 30:3

Comment: @MosheSF, the פרשת דרכים writes that Reuven’s relations with Bilhah was not forbidden for this reason

Comment: @User123  could you provide that source so we can read that actual words?

Comment: Genesis 37:12 explicitly states that Bilha and Zilpah were wives (not concubines): אֵ֣לֶּה | תֹּֽלְד֣וֹת יַֽעֲקֹ֗ב יוֹסֵ֞ף בֶּן־שְׁבַע־עֶשְׂרֵ֤ה שָׁנָה֙ הָיָ֨ה רֹעֶ֤ה אֶת־אֶחָיו֙ בַּצֹּ֔אן וְה֣וּא נַ֗עַר אֶת־בְּנֵ֥י בִלְהָ֛ה וְאֶת־בְּנֵ֥י זִלְפָּ֖ה נְשֵׁ֣י אָבִ֑יו וַיָּבֵ֥א יוֹסֵ֛ף אֶת־דִּבָּתָ֥ם רָעָ֖ה אֶל־אֲבִיהֶֽם:

Comment: @MosheSF, Genesis 35:22 says that Bilhah was a concubine

Comment: @MosheSF "_the question has nothing to do with Rochel and Leah, just zilpah, the twin sister of Jacob's wife Bilha._" The question rest on the premise that marrying Rochel and Leah was not a problem, and supports it with the claim I quoted in my comment. I'm questioning this claim, and by extension, that premise your question rests on. Personally, without answers to the questions I posed, I'm with [Dov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138265/how-is-it-that-yaakov-avinu-was-permitted-to-marry-zilpah-because-she-was-the-s#comment461266_138265) on this one.